# How to work with Task Parallel library with DataReader

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

i often populate data reader with data and populate UI like this way

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from employee where salary<5000", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // here i populate my employee class
        }
    }
    // here i update UI
}
```

i was searching for the use of Task Parallel library with DataReader and found piece of code. it looks nice but objective is not very clear to me. so here is the code i got.

```
public IEnumerable<MyDataClass> ReadData()
{
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("myQuery", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return new MyDataClass(... data from reader ...);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**calling like**

```
Parallel.ForEach(this.ReadData(), data =>
{
// Use the data here...
});
```

OR

```
this.ReadData().AsParallel().ForAll(data => 
{
// Use the data here...
});
```

how could i get the data from **ForAll**.

can anyone help me to understand the code snippet that how it works and how to get data from **ForAll** and how can i populate my UI from **ForAll**.

another question that how do i know that which class is thread safe or not. what does it mean thread safe. a person said datareader is not thread safe. how he knows.

another question when one should use task parallel library.
please guide. thanks

Comment: If you are want to use TPL 'just to use it' while you don't have a performance problem, then I wouldn't bother. It makes thinks more complex than you can imagine at the moment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find information about thread-safety of every type in the .NET base class library in the MSDN documentation. Most types are **not** thread-safe. `SqlDataReader` for instance, is **not** thread-safe, since it works on a single connection to the database.

However, `Parallel.ForEach` is a very clearer construct. You can't really iterate an `IEnumerable` with multiple thread simultaneously, and `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't do that. Although it spins up multiple threads and those multiple threads do iterate on the given `IEnumerable`, `Parallel.ForEach` ensures that only **one** thread at the time iterates the enumerable's `IEnumerator`. It operates on the assumption that processing elements takes more time than getting the items from the enumerable. Iterating the enumerable is a sequential operation.

This means that even if the underlying data source and the use of the `SqlReader` is not thread-safe, you can still process the items in parallel using the `Parallel.ForEach`. Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation isn't very explicit about this, but it has to be, since `IEnumerator` instances returned from `GetEnumerator()` methods are never thread-safe.

Still you have to make sure that the given `Action<T>` is thread-safe, of course.

You can see this behavior, using the following program:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 140; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "                          Enumerating " + 
            i + " at thread " +
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        yield return i;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ReadLine();

    Parallel.ForEach(GetNumbers(), number =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing " + number + 
            " at thread " +
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Thread.Sleep(1);
    });
}
```

Comment: people often said that this class is not thread-safe like datareader is not thread-safe. may be they are right but i dont know which dotnet build-in classes are thread-safe or not. so i want to know how people detect that any specific class is thread-safe or not and what they try to mean thread-safe? help me to know how to detect class is thread-safe or not. thanks

Comment: The MSDN documentation of each type explains if it is thread-safe or not. If it doesn't state explicitly, it usually isn't thread-safe. Thread-safe means that an instance of a type can be used simultaniously from multiple threads, without the chance that the state of that instance (or the whole system) gets corrupt.

Comment: Seems like AsParallel().ForAll is safe too.