# Understanding AsParallel and AsSequential: which part of the LINQ query is concurrent?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq

I'm trying to understand if I can use a non thread-safe class left to a `AsParallel` query. Something like:

```
src.Select(item => nonSafeClass.Process(item))
   .AsParallel()
   .Select(item => DoComputationalIntenseButThreadSafeWork(item));
```

I've tried to run the following code to see which part of the query chain is executed in parallel in which is not:

```
IEnumerable<int> array = Enumerable.Range(0, short.MaxValue).ToArray();
array.Select(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step One: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return i;
    }).AsParallel().Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Two: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;

        }).AsSequential().Select(i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Step Three: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                return i;
            }).ToList();
```

But to my surprise, both "Step One" and "Step Three" appear on different thread IDs. I was expecting to see different thread IDs only for "Step Two" because it is between a `AsParallel` and a `AsSequential`. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: as long as the reads are thread-safe and you are only doing reads, you should be good to go. writes are a different issue though ...

Comment: what you have to understand is that IEnumerables are lazy - they are only consumed on demand - so if you have a AsParallel somewhere then `nonSafeClass.Process` will be called later on a possible different thread. If you don't want to have this just **eager** force it for example with `src.Select(...).ToArray()....`

Comment: @CarstenKönig: I was suspecting something like this. Still, I don't understand then the use of AsSequential. Also, in my actual code, in the "non thread-safe section" left of the AsParallel, i have a DbDataReader that I advance in a `yield return`. And it works! Just that I don't know why. I doubt DbDataReader is thread-safe...

Comment: @CarstenKönig: ah, I've found the answer to that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949028/how-to-work-with-task-parallel-library-with-datareader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

And [how chained queries in Linq work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669166.aspx).

If you change it to the simplest case of

```
array.Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step One: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;
        }).Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Two: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;

        }).Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Three: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;
        }).ToList();
```

You will see this:
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
...
...

Now imagine if your assumption was correct:

First Select() runs on `Thread 1` (main thread). Then your `AsParallel` runs on a different thread but finally, your final `AsSequential()` needs to run on the same thread, meaning it doesn't make any difference to have the `AsParallel` running on a different thread since `Thread 1` is blocked.

The flow you were thinking would be: 
`1 -> x -> 1`

followed by 
`1 -> y -> 1`

and so on and so forth.

As an optimization, when Linq detects that you have a select followed by `AsParallel`, it runs them for each iteration on a separate thread. Again, this is because going from `1 -> x -> 1 -> y` wouldn't make anything run in "parallel".

Try it by running a simplified version:

```
array.Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step One: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;
        }).AsParallel().Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Two: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;

        }).ToList();
```

You will see that Step 1 and Step 2 are don in "sequence" but each iteration is done on a different thread.

Your AsSequential() however will run on the main thread that executed it.

As such, I would expect Step 1 and Step 2 to *run on the same thread which is different from the calling thread* but Step 3 to run on the same thread that started the chain.

If you want to achieve the behavior you described, simply change your query to this:

```
array.Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step One: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;
        }).ToList().AsParallel().Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Two: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;

        }).AsSequential().Select(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step Three: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return i;
        }).ToList();
```

The first ToList() evaluation will run everything on the calling thread, the AsParallel() then runs each iteration on a different thread (subject to ThreadPool availability) and finally, your AsSequential will make sure the sequential bits are run on the calling thread.

Comment: It does make sense what you're saying. Thanks a lot. Only that in my case, forcing evaluation with `ToList` is not an option because I have many elements to process (not fitting in memory). And what is even weirder is that I do iterate over a DbDataReader which I doubt is thread-safe. But I'll check on that in a separate question if needed.

Comment: Ah, I've found the answer for the DbDataReader case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949028/how-to-work-with-task-parallel-library-with-datareader