# Impact of using AsParallel() and AsSequential() in the same query? C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, plinq

I was going through PLINQ in one of the books and it said:

> If you have a complex query that can benefit from parallel processing
>   but also has some parts that should be done sequentially, you can use
>   the AsSequential to stop your query from being processed in parallel.

For Example:

```
var parallelResult = numbers.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
    .Where(i => i % 2 == 0).AsSequential();
```

I want to understand why is it allowed and what is the impact on the result? Is it running parallel? Is it running sequential? It isn't making any sense right now.

Comment: The code `i % 2 == 0` inside the `Where` lambda will run parallely in multiple threads. Is this what you want? The `AsSequential` at the end of the query has no impact, because there are no more calculations happening after that.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I want to know if there are any benefits of calling these two methods together.

Comment: It's one of those cases by "in case of...". For instance, if you want to fetch data, you can fetch everything parallel. Now thats great and will be faster than doing it in sequences. But sometimes you'll have to do some more logic which will have to evaluate each value one by one. For instance during a order by. You won't be able to do this Parallel because you´ll need to preserve the ordering that was established in a previous clause of the query. [Here is a nice example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-combine-parallel-and-sequential-linq-queries)

Comment: About AsParallel() and AsSequential(), maybe you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29124656/8335151

Answer (score 1):

You may conceptualize a LINQ query as an atomic construct with a single execution plan, but it may be more helpful to conceptualize is as a pipeline consisting of multiple dataflow blocks. The output of each block becomes the input of the next block in the dataflow, and the blocks are processing items concurrently, as soon as they become available. Take a look for example to the next query, consisting of two "blocks" represented by the two `Select` operators. The first block is configured to process 3 items at a time (in parallel), while to second block is configured to process each item sequentially. The processing duration of each item is 1000 msec for the parallel block, and 500 msec for the sequential block:

```
var results = Partitioner
    .Create(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
    .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}"
            + $" [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Parallel #{x}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate some CPU-bound work
        return x;
    })
    .AsSequential()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}"
            + $" [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Sequential #{x}");
        Thread.Sleep(500); // Simulate some CPU-bound work
        return x;
    })
    .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Results: {String.Join(", ", results)}");
```

If you run this code you'll get an output like this:

```xml
08:32:17.628 [4] Parallel #2
08:32:17.628 [5] Parallel #1
08:32:17.628 [6] Parallel #3
08:32:18.642 [6] Parallel #5
08:32:18.642 [5] Parallel #4
08:32:18.644 [4] Parallel #6
08:32:18.651 [1] Sequential #1
08:32:19.644 [6] Parallel #7
08:32:19.645 [4] Parallel #8
08:32:19.646 [5] Parallel #9
08:32:19.654 [1] Sequential #2
08:32:20.156 [1] Sequential #3
08:32:20.648 [4] Parallel #10
08:32:20.658 [1] Sequential #4
08:32:21.161 [1] Sequential #5
08:32:21.663 [1] Sequential #6
08:32:22.164 [1] Sequential #7
08:32:22.672 [1] Sequential #8
08:32:23.173 [1] Sequential #9
08:32:23.675 [1] Sequential #10
Results: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Notice how the sequential processing is already started before all parallel processing has been completed. To achieve this effect I used the configuration options [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) and [`ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions), to prevent the first block from buffering its input and output.

For completeness lets rewrite this query using the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. The code becomes more verbose and less fluent, but the control of execution becomes more precise, and also asynchronous workflows become available (PLINQ is not async-friendly):

```
var block1 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(async x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}"
        + $" [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Parallel #{x}");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate some I/O operation
    return x;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3,
    EnsureOrdered = true // redundant since EnsureOrdered is the default
});

var block2 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(async x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}"
        + $" [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Sequential #{x}");
    await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate some I/O operation
    return x;
}); // MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 is the default

block1.LinkTo(block2, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

// Feeding the first block
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    await block1.SendAsync(x);
}
block1.Complete();

var results = new List<int>(); // Collecting the results is a bit painful
while (await block2.OutputAvailableAsync())
{
    while (block2.TryReceive(out var result))
    {
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
await block2.Completion;
Console.WriteLine($"Results: {String.Join(", ", results)}");
```

Output:

```xml
08:59:25.102 [6] Parallel #2
08:59:25.102 [4] Parallel #1
08:59:25.102 [7] Parallel #3
08:59:26.127 [7] Parallel #4
08:59:26.129 [6] Parallel #5
08:59:26.143 [4] Parallel #6
08:59:26.147 [5] Sequential #1
08:59:26.648 [5] Sequential #2
08:59:27.129 [6] Parallel #7
08:59:27.129 [7] Parallel #8
08:59:27.144 [4] Parallel #9
08:59:27.149 [5] Sequential #3
08:59:27.650 [5] Sequential #4
08:59:28.131 [6] Parallel #10
08:59:28.152 [5] Sequential #5
08:59:28.653 [5] Sequential #6
08:59:29.155 [5] Sequential #7
08:59:29.659 [5] Sequential #8
08:59:30.160 [5] Sequential #9
08:59:30.674 [5] Sequential #10
Results: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```